# Accepting XML on server side using RESTEasy

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, resteasy

I want to create a REFTful web service that accepts XML. I can see a lot of examples where server is sending response as an XML. But I want to process request as an XML. 
Anyone has idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JAXB to map XML to Java classes.

```
@PUT
@Accepts("application/xml")
public Response putThing(Thing theThing) {
  // save theThing
  URI theThingUri = new URI(...);
  return Response.created(theThingUri).build();
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Thing {
  // members, constructors, getter, setter
}
```

See [the RESTEasy documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html/Built_in_JAXB_providers.html).